# How to determine / make sure whether hard-disks have spun down when using "hdparm" options?

Tags: hardware, hard-drive, disk-usage, power-management, spindown

I want to spin down some hard-disks when they are idle. So I used ***hdparm*** package. In the  `/etc/hdparm.conf` I added following lines:

```
command_line {
hdparm -Ss 241 /dev/sda }
```

My intention was to spin down hard disk after 30 minutes of idle time. However, my problem is, how I know for sure whether hard disk has spun down (assuming that it had exceed idle time of 30 minutes)??

Any ideas? Tips?? :) :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `hdparm -C /dev/sda`. From `man hdparm`:

```
   -C     Check the current IDE power mode status, which will always be  one
          of  unknown  (drive  does  not  support this command), active/idle
          (normal operation), standby (low power mode, drive has spun down),
          or  sleeping  (lowest  power mode, drive is completely shut down).
          The -S, -y, -Y, and -Z options can be used to manipulate  the  IDE
          power modes.
```